# Какой условный оператор использовать, для того чтобы программа не заканчивалась?

Tags: ruby

Приветствую всех, перейду сразу к сути.

**Задача от программы:** отвечать на вопросы собеседника.

**Проблема:** после ответа на один вопрос программа заканчивается.

**Вопрос:** что использовать, для того, чтобы программа не заканчивалась на ответе на один вопрос?

*В программе я использовал условный оператор IF, но предполагаю, что нужно использовать какой-то цикл, или что-то в этом роде. Заранее большое спасибо за помощь.*

```
#Массивы с универсальными ответами
massive_a = [
    "Я не знаю, что тебе ответить.",
    "Меня ещё не научили отвечать на этот вопрос.",
    "Может спросишь по другому?",
    "Давай сменим тему?",
    "Я не хочу отвечать на этот вопрос",
    "Этот вопрос слишком сложный для меня, извини."
]
massive_b = [
    "А где волшебное слово?",
    "Простого пожалуйста было бы достаточно.",
    "Где твоя вежливость? А как же пожалуйста?"
]

#Начало программы

puts "Привет, я Руби, твой личный ассистент."
sleep 1
puts "Как тебя зовут?"
player_name = gets.chomp.encode ('UTF-8')
puts "Приятно познакомится, " + player_name + "."
sleep 1
puts "Чем могу помочь?"

answer = gets.chomp.encode ('UTF-8')
if answer == "Руби, что ты умеешь?"
    sleep 0.5
    puts "Я умею отвечать на простые вопросы, могу помочь тебе с открытием"
    sleep 1
    puts "какой-нибудь программы на твоём компьютере. Также я могу выполнить"
    sleep 1
    puts "поисковый запрос по твоему желанию."
elsif answer == "руби что ты умеешь?"
    sleep 0.5
    puts "Я умею отвечать на простые вопросы, могу помочь тебе с открытием"
    sleep 1
    puts "какой-нибудь программы на твоём компьютере. Также я могу выполнить"
    sleep 1
    puts "поисковый запрос по твоему желанию."
elsif answer == "Руби что ты умеешь?"
    sleep 0.5
    puts "Я умею отвечать на простые вопросы, могу помочь тебе с открытием"
    sleep 1
    puts "какой-нибудь программы на твоём компьютере. Также я могу выполнить"
    sleep 1
    puts "поисковый запрос по твоему желанию."
elsif answer == "Руби что ты умеешь"
    sleep 0.5
    puts "Я умею отвечать на простые вопросы, могу помочь тебе с открытием"
    sleep 1
    puts "какой-нибудь программы на твоём компьютере. Также я могу выполнить"
    sleep 1
    puts "поисковый запрос по твоему желанию."
elsif answer == "руби что ты умеешь"
    sleep 0.5
    puts "Я умею отвечать на простые вопросы, могу помочь тебе с открытием"
    sleep 1
    puts "какой-нибудь программы на твоём компьютере. Также я могу выполнить"
    sleep 1
    puts "поисковый запрос по твоему желанию."
elsif answer == "Какая сегодня погода?"
    sleep 0.5
    puts massive_a.sample
elsif answer == "Как тебя зовут?"
    puts "Меня зовут Руби."
elsif answer == "Какая сегодня погода?"
    sleep 0.5
    puts massive_a.sample
else
    sleep 0.5
    puts massive_a.sample
end
```

Comment: в вашем случае лучше использовать оператор case вместо if

Answer (score 2):

[Ruby Community Style Guide рекомендует пользоваться `Kernel#loop`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#infinite-loop) для организации бесконечного цикла вместо `while`/`until`:

```
loop do
  # что повторять
end
```

Функциональной разницы по сравнению с `while true` нет, просто лучше читается.

Comment: Пробовал, получается, что программа бесконечно раз начинает отвечать на один и тот же вопрос.

Comment: @greenwookez значит просто неправильно логику пишете

Comment: @greenwookez мне тут намекают свыше, что вы оставили строчку `answer = ...` снаружи `loop`'а.

Comment: @D-side я вставил `loop do` в самом начале программы и `end` в самом конце.

Comment: @greenwookez в этом случае программа будет себя вести вовсе не так, как вы описали.

Comment: @D-side прошу прощения за мою некомпетентность, похоже я нашёл решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вашей задачи можно использовать оператор цикла while. Например, этот код будет бесконечно печатать Hello

```
while true do
    puts "Hello"
end
```

Для прерывания цикла можно использовать оператор `break`

Поставьте `while true do` перед строчкой `puts "Привет, я Руби, твой личный ассистент."`, `end` в самом конце программы. Тогда программа будет выполняться в бесконечном цикле. Остановить работу можно будет при помощи комбинации клавиш `Ctrl+Break`